# How do I draw all the border to angular grid list material?

Tags: html, css, angular, grid

I am working on angular material grid list. How can I apply/draw black border and its thickness on all the mat-grid-tile as shown below? What is the class name to edit the css for the mat-grid-tile?

```
<mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="200px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="1">Text</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="1">Text</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="1">Text</mat-grid-tile>    
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="1">Text</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this via CSS only.

While inspecting you will see there is class called `mat-grid-tile`.

On that class you add following css will help you provide the border & also you can control the thickness, color etc...

```
.mat-grid-tile {
    border: solid 2px #000;
}
```

Check the below StackBlitz where i add the same css in `style.scss`.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-grid-example-pbr7m3?file=styles.scss)